# iOS Auto Layout: Set the trailing space equal to the width of the superview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I need to position a view just outside the right bound of its superview using auto layout.

I'm trying to do this by specifying the following NSLayoutConstraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.downloadView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0.0];
```

Where self.downloadView holds is a subviews of self.contentView.
By doing so iOS complain with the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Invalid pairing of layout attributes'
```

Someone can explain why I can't pair this two attributes and how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you cannot set the leading attribute to be related to the width attribute of the `contentView`. But you could, for example, set the leading attribute of the `downloadView` to be relative to the trailing attribute of its `superview`, the `contentView`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.downloadView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0.0];
```

Or you could define the leading attribute of the `downloadView` to be relative to the leading attribute of the `contentView`, but then set the `constant` to be some value, such as the width of the view. The problem with that technique, though, that on orientation changes, the `constant` wouldn't be appropriate any more and you might have to adjust it.

Comment: I had figure it out the same by setting the constant as the view's width. But as you told if the orientation change this stops to work. I prefer an orientationchange-safe solution.

Comment: @LucaBernardi Yep, the first approach I outline is orientation-safe solution.